# Autocomplete field not using Entity Reference list settings

Tags: views, 8, entities, ajax

I'm using an Entity Reference field set to **Views: Filter by an entity reference view**. That works. I can choose my view: **maps_by_project_season – Entity Reference**.

I've chosen 3 fields in the view, and added them all to **Format: Entity Reference list** via **settings**, and I see all 3, separated by -, in the preview.

But not in the autocomplete field. That only shows the title. What am I missing?

Comment: This is a known bug in Drupal 8, see: [View output is not used for autocomplete display](https://www.drupal.org/node/2174633) you could try the patch in #76.

Comment: Thanks! Would you like to move your comment to an answer so I can flag it as correct? Also – 3 years since the original posting there?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in Drupal 8, see: [View output is not used for autocomplete display](https://www.drupal.org/node/2174633) you could try the patch in #76

There was also another disccusion about the same thing here [Views Filter by an entity reference view not working as expected](https://www.drupal.org/node/2714089), before it was closed as duplicate.